# How do i Create sql login user with using QUERY?

Tags: sql-server, login

How do i Create sql login user with using QUERY?
I would like to use the following parameters.

1. User Name = **campus**
2. User's Password = **123**
3. Policy = **OFF**
4. Default Language = **English**
5. Default Database = **VM1**
6. Server Role = **Public**
7. User Mapping = **V** checked on my database name (**VM1**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft SQL Server:

```
use VM1
Go
create login campus With PASSWORD='123', DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=english, check_policy=off, default_database=VM1
Go
Create user campus for Login campus
Go
```

The public role on server is created by default.

Creating the user on the database will map that database to the Server login.